# syntax error, unexpected 'function_construct' WEB SERVICE PHP

Tags: php, xml

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar um webservice porem quando vou executar ele me apresenta esses erros[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu tenho 3 arquivos nesse webservice segue o código

acesso.php

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/json/index.php");
    print_r($xml);

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('html-class.php');


$xml = new Xml();
$db = 'localhost:F:\Dados\TGA.FDB';
$username = 'SYSDBA';
$password = 'masterkey';
// Connect to database
$idmov = $_GET['id'];
$erro = 0;
$xml -> openTag("response");
$dbh = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password);
if($idmov == ''){
    $erro = 1;
    $msgerro = 'Codigo invalido!';
  }
  else{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TMOV WHERE IDMOV = $idmov';
    $rc = ibase_query($dbh, $sql);
    if(ibase_fetch_row($rc) > 0){
      $reg = ibase_fetch_object($rc);
      $xml-> addTag('IDMOV', $reg -> IDMOV);
      $xml-> addTag('CODCFO', $reg -> CODCFO);
  }    

}
$xml -> addTag('erro', $erro);
$xml -> addTag('msgerro', $msgerro);

$xml -> closetag("response");
echo $xml;
?>
```

html-class.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * 
     */
    class Xml{
        private $xml;
        private $tab = 1;
        public function_construct($version = '1', $encode = 'UTF-8'){
            $this ->xml .= "<?xml version = '$version' encoding = '$encode' ?> \n";
        }
        public function openTag($name){
            $this -> addTab();
            $this -> xml .= "<$name>\n";
            $this ->tab++;

        }
        public function closeTag($name){
            $this ->tab--;
            $this -> addTab();
            $this ->xml .= "</$name>\n";

        }
        public function setValue($value){
            $this -> xml .= "$value\n"
        }
        private function addTab(){
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $this ->tab; $i++){
                $this -> xml .= "\t";
            }
        }
        public function addTag($name, $value){
            $this -> addTab();
            $this ->xml .= "<$name>$value</$name>\n";
        }
        public function _toString(){
            return $this ->xml;
        }
    }

?>
```

Então eu já procurei erro de virgula, todos que eu achei eu corrigi, e agora estou perdido no que pode ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O XML não está sendo gerado no `index.php`, se você acessa-se diretamente iria notar a mensagem de erro, então o problema não é no `simple_load_xml`, você escreveu no `index.php`:

```
public function_construct($version = '1', $encode = 'UTF-8'){
```

Quando deveria ter escrito:

```
public function _construct($version = '1', $encode = 'UTF-8'){
```

É erro de digitação, provavelmente você apagou o espaço entre functio e __construtct acidentalmente.

Comment: após eu corrigir esse erro agora ele retorna esse 

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 13

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Xml could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 35

Comment: @MatheusMartins é só ler o erro e ver qual a linha, tá faltando definir o id na url do index.php para pegar, mas eu não tenho como adivinhar a origem do ID, o que posso dizer é que vocÊ tem que fazer algo assim: `$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/json/index.php?id=VALOR_DO_ID");`, mas de onde vc vai obter eu não tenho como saber, pois o teu acesso.php só tem duas linhas

Comment: Muito obrigado, desculpa as pergunta meio ignorante que eu sou novo, mas já me ajudou demais.

Comment: Por nada @MatheusMartins, o que importa é descrever também o objetivo na pergunta, pq as vezes só olhando o erro não dá pra ajudar totalmente, se disser como deve funcionar ajuda a ajuda-lo ;)